# How can I extract the angular font awesome library into a separate module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, font-awesome

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome with great success, but as I add more icons my app.module.ts in increasing in size:

[image]

Is there a way to extract this code into a separate file to handle my icon libraries, and then import that file into app.module.ts so all my components can access it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a module which exports it:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
....

/**
 * Implementation for the icon logic.
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    faVideo,
    faList,
    ....
  ],
  exports: [
    faVideo,
    faList,
    ....
  ],
})
export class IconModule {}
```

Then in your app.module:

```
import { IconModule } from './modules/icon'`
```

And import it

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    IconModule
   ],
 })
```

However, that is one reason why I just use the CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can create a separate module in, for example, `app/core/modules`.

[icon.module.ts]

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary, FaConfig } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

import { faCoffee, faHouse } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
})
export class IconModule { 
  constructor(faConfig: FaConfig, library: FaIconLibrary,) {
    // Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
    faConfig.defaultPrefix = 'far';
    faConfig.fixedWidth = true;
    library.addIcons(faCoffee, faHouse);
  }
}
```

then, if you want to use it globally, you must import it into `app.module`

[app.module.ts]

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { IconModule } from './core/modules/icon/icon.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [ AppRoutingModule, FontAwesomeModule, IconModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

not that you need to still import `FontAwesomeModule` here so that `<fa-icon>` tag is available in all your html files.